# A Function reading from an Azure Service Bus and loading connection configuration from Azure KeyVault

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-7.0, azure-servicebus-queues

I have this function using .NET 7 and Isolated Functions

```
[Function(nameof(SomeFunction))]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger(QueueConsts.DefaultPricingQueue, 
    Connection = "Common:ServiceBus:ConnectionString")] 
    ServiceBusReceivedMessage message)
```

And this is how my `Programe.cs` looks like:

```
using Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

IHost host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((host, configBuilder) =>
    {
        configBuilder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        if (host.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            configBuilder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json");
        }

        configBuilder.AddUserSecrets<Program>();

        string? keyVaultAddress = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyVault__Address");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyVaultAddress))
        {
            configBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
                new Uri(keyVaultAddress!),
                new DefaultAzureCredential(),
                new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions
                {
                    ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)
                });
        }
    })
    .ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration configuration = host.Configuration;
        IConfiguration dbConfig = configuration.GetSection("DB");
        services.Configure<DbConfiguration>(dbConfig);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

I am using the Function configuration and overriding it with KeyVault. I can access any secret in this way in a transparent way. This is a standard ASP.NET implementation, I am not doing anything special.

When I put my configuration in the Function configuration as `Common:ServiceBus:ConnectionString` , I am able to launch my Function as expected but when I move it to the Azure KeyVault, it fails to access it. But if I try to access it via KeyVault from another part of my application, I can read it as expected. So that meant that my `ServiceBusTrigger` is not looking at the KeyVault.

Can the `ServiceBusTrigger` request the `Connection` from KeyVault? Do I need to change my dependency configuration?

Comment: I think the answer on this one is "No" (Can the ServiceBusTrigger request the Connection from KeyVault? Do I need to change my dependency configuration?). However, if you use the default Key Vault references, I believe it will work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

Answer (score 1):

> Can the `ServiceBusTrigger` request the `Connection` from KeyVault?

Yes, you can achieve it using secret identifier of the connection string which is stored in key vault.

Thanks **@silent**, for the suggestion in the comment.

[image]

To fetch the Service Bus connection string from key vault, you need to add the below line in your local setting file.

```
"ServiceBusConnection" : "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<Your secret identifier from key vault>"
```

**`local.settings.json:`**

```
{

"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"afreenserviceBus_SERVICEBUS": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=Your service bus connection strings secret identifier from key vault)"
}
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: This is referenced here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault