# Service Bus account connection string Not found from Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-keyvault, azure-functions-isolated

I have an Isolated Azure Function written in .net 7, triggered by Service Bus.
I am trying to move my Connection string (and other credentials to KeyVault Secrets)

I already have created a Keyvault secret named **ServiceBusConnectionString**.

This is my simplified app.settings.json (which I have a similar Configuration in Azure Function)

```
"Values": {
"KeyVaultUri": "https://xxxxxxx-vault.vault.azure.net/",
  "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
  "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
  "StorageConnectionString": "Moved to Keyvault",
  "ServiceBusConnectionString": "Moved to Keyvault"
}
```

This is my simplified Program.cs:

```
    internal class Program
 {
     private static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         string keyVaultUri = string.Empty;
         SecretClient _secretClient;
         var host = new HostBuilder()
     .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
     .ConfigureOpenApi()
     .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
     {
          var builtConfig = config.Build();
          keyVaultUri = builtConfig["KeyVaultUri"];
          builtConfig = config.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
     })
     .ConfigureServices(services =>
     {
         _secretClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
         services.AddOptions<DemandwareSettings>().Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
         {
             configuration.GetSection("Demandware").Bind(settings);
             settings.SFCCCustomerListId = _secretClient.GetSecret(configuration["SFCCCustomerListId"]).Value.Value;
         });
         services.AddSingleton<ISQLHelper, SQLHelper>();
         services.AddHttpClient();
     })
     .Build();
        host.Run();
     }
 }
```

And finally this is my Azure Function:

```
public class UpdateInvoices
{
    [Function("UpdateInvoices")]
     public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("omssalespostings", "canadagoosetoods", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string msg)
    {
        //....
    }
}
```

While running this Azure function locally I get this error message:

*The listener for function 'Functions.UpdateInvoices' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus: Service Bus account connection string 'ServiceBusConnectionString' does not exist. Make sure that it is a defined App Setting.*

[image]
However, when I add `.build()` at end of the line 18 in `Program.cs` and a breakpoint for `builtConfig`, then I retrieve builtConfig["ServiceBusConnectionString"] with **Immediate Window**, I get the missing Connection string value. (plz see below snapshot)
[image]

Note: I don't wan't to set

```
"ServiceBusConnection" : "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=<Y...
```

in my `local.settings.json.`
This is why
[A Function reading from an Azure Service Bus and loading connection configuration from Azure KeyVault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76762380/a-function-reading-from-an-azure-service-bus-and-loading-connection-configuratio)
doesn't work for me.

Comment: I did not found any proper answer so I went through this path:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#source-app-settings-from-key-vault and replaced it with "ServiceBusConnectionString": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=XXXXXXXX-vaultname;SecretName=ServiceBusConnectionString)" in both local.settings.json and Azure Function Configuration